# Laravel - Form checkbox not getting checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

In Laravel I am fetching the value from database and based on that adding condition to check checkbox. I am facing issue with laravel checkbox is not getting checked. Tried using following code:

```
// outputting value from database to input field
{{Form::text('lock_user_role',null,array('class'=>'form-control')) }} 
              
// if lock user value is 1 in database then need to check checkbox 
{{Form::checkbox('lock_user_role', 'lock_user_role', 'lock_user_role' === '1' ? true : false)}}
```

Here is my database column structure:
[image]

Here is my column value getting stored:

[image]

Here is my actual output shown:

[image]

As shown in above image, value is showing 1 but checkbox is not getting checked. Can anyone correct my code ? Thanks

Comment: Look at this line: `lock_user_role' === '1' ? true : false`. That is _never_ going to be `true`. When would the string `'lock_user_role'` ever strictly equal `'1'`? Never. You're basically calling `Form::checkbox('lock_user_role', 'lock_user_role', false)` so it should be obvious why it's not being checked.

Comment: Hint, did you maybe mean to use the `old` helper, or a reference to a Model instance, like `old('lock_user_role', $user->lock_role_user) == 1 ? true : false`

Answer (score 1):

If the value fetched from database is integer 1 then the strict comparison (===) will evaluate to false.

Try replacing with loose comparison (==)

And comparison between string literal `lock_user_role` and any other string or integer will always be false `'lock_user_role' == '1'` will always evaluate to false - as pointed out by @TimLewis.

So it should be something like `$user->lock_user_role` or `$lock_user_role` - a variable

```php
// if lock user value is 1 in database then need to check checkbox 
{{Form::checkbox('lock_user_role', 'lock_user_role', $user->lock_user_role == '1' ? true : false)}}
```

Comment: Valid point on loose comparison, but `'lock_user_role' == '1'` is still `false` 

Comment: @TimLewis Haha yeah. Completely missed that a string literal is being compared to another string. **lock_user_role** should be a variable like `$user->lock_user_role` or `$lock_user_role`

Comment: No worries! I thought the same thing as you at first. That looks better, as long as `$user` (or whatever) is defined in the form. Cheers!